# Can an HtmlHelper library be compatible with both MVC-3 and MVC-4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am trying to create an HtmlHelper library that will work in both MVC-3 and MVC-4 projects.

I've been able to get a library that is compatible between MVC-2 and MVC-3 by setting the framework reference in the library to MVC-2, but MVC-2 is not the concern.

If I set the framework reference in the library to MVC-3, when an MVC-4 project uses one of the helpers, the method in the helper-library thows an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception.

The helper has a signature like this:

```
public static IHtmlString InputTagFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
```

And the null reference exception comes at this point in the method:

```
var value = expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model).ToString();
```

because htmlHelper.ViewData.Model is `null`.

If I switch the framework reference to MVC-4, (and system.web.webpages to v2) it all works in an MVC-4 app; but, of course, it wont' work in an MVC-3 app.

**So, my question is**: is it possible to Create an HtmlHelper library that is compatible between the these fraemwork versions, and how?

**update** Screenshots of the helper-method at a break-point, with the watch window showing values for the htmlHelper...

#### Helper method invoked from an MVC-3 app:

[image: Library helper invoked from an MVC-3 app]

#### Helper method invoked from an MVC-4 app:

[image: Library helper invoked from an MVC-4 app]

...and for the record the model `HomePage` is defined independently, but identically inside each MVC app with just one field (`TestStringField`), and the controller action is returning thusly:

```
return View(new HomePage{TestStringField = "a string value"});
```

While the helper is being called from a strongly-typed (to `HomePage`) Razor view in a like this:

```
@Html.InputTagFor(model => model.TestStringField)
```

Comment: That's very weird that you're getting different errors like that. Is the htmlHelper.ViewData null or the htmlHelper.ViewData.Model null? What is the model when it is not null (in the mvc3 app)?

Comment: @Kyle: htmlHelper.ViewData is not null (but .Model is). In the mvc3 app, the model is appropriately typed <Mvc3TestApp.Models.HomePage>, even in the MVC4 app, the model *type* is correct -- it's just null. See screenshots in my update.

Comment: And you're sure that on the view the model is not null?

Comment: @Kyle: The model, as attached to htlmHelper.ViewData, *is* null, though I have not tried to inspect  the model directly from the view. I don't expect tht to be null, but I'll take a look at work tomorrow and post another comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because if your library references ASP.NET MVC 3 then the consumer of your library should use that, unless ... he uses a `<bindingRedirect>` in which case he is assuming the responsibility of the breaking changes that might occur between the 2 versions of MVC.

Honestly, forget about that. Just ship 2 different versions of your library, or if you are using more advanced shipping mechanisms (than a copy paste of a DLL), you could ship 2 different NuGet versions of your helpers. Just like everyone else does. For example you've got `Unity.MVC3` and `Unity.MVC4`.

Comment: This is what I figured I'd have to do as well. A question that pops up... how do you set up a project of html helpers so that it builds both dlls for mvc3 and mvc4 (and probably mvc5 soon). I created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188504/how-to-set-up-project-of-htmlhelpers-so-that-it-produces-two-dlls-for-mvc3-and) for this. Would appreciate help